# No such file or directory, when using Vite and Antd Pro Layout

Tags: antd, ant-design-pro, vite

No such file or directory, when using Vite and Antd Pro Layout

This is file vite.config.ts:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import reactRefresh from '@vitejs/plugin-react-refresh';
import path from 'path';
import vitePluginImp from 'vite-plugin-imp';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    reactRefresh(),
    vitePluginImp({
      libList: [
        {
          libName: 'antd',
          style: (name) => {
            return `antd/lib/${name}/style/index.less`;
          },
        },
      ],
    }),
  ],
  css: {
    preprocessorOptions: {
      less: {
        javascriptEnabled: true,
        modifyVars: {
          ...{
            'primary-color': '#1DA57A',
            'link-color': '#1DA57A',
            'border-radius-base': '2px',
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: [
      {
        find: /^~/,
        replacement: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
      },
    ],
  },
  optimizeDeps: {
    include: ['@ant-design/icons'],
  },
});
```

This is my config to using antd, antd-pro-layout with vite.

But I received the error:

```
[vite] Internal server error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 
'/Users/tranthaison/DEV/vite2-react-ts/srcantd/es/style/themes/default.less'
```

Can someone help me to fix it?

Comment: This is my error [vite] Internal server error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/tranthaison/DEV/vite2-react-ts/srcantd/es/style/themes/default.less'

Answer (score 11):

I had some problems when using React + Antd in Vite.

Thanks for @theprimone for the answer. But the answer is incomplete. I will complete the answer here.

---

**First time, add additional config to Less Preprocessor:**

Add this config to your `vite.config.js` file:

```js
{
  css: {
    preprocessorOptions: {
      less: {
        javascriptEnabled: true,
      },
    },
  },
}
```

---

**Second, setting module aliases to fix Less `@import` problem:**

Again, add the following config into your `vite.config.js` file:

```js
{
  resolve: {
    alias: [
      { find: /^~/, replacement: "" },
    ],
  },
}
```

---

**Last, install `vite-plugin-imp` plugin to solve *Antd ES problem*:**

Install the `vite-plugin-imp` dependencies:

```sh
pnpm add -D vite-plugin-imp

# or

npm i -D vite-plugin-imp
```

then, setup the plugin in your `vite.config.js` file:

```js
{
  plugins: [
    // React plugin here
    
    vitePluginImp({
      libList: [
        {
          libName: "antd",
          style: (name) => `antd/es/${name}/style`,
        },
      ],
    }),
  ];
}
```

---

**The final configuration in `vite.config.js` file will look like this:**

```js
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import reactRefresh from '@vitejs/plugin-react-refresh';
import vitePluginImp from "vite-plugin-imp";

export default defineConfig({
  css: {
    preprocessorOptions: {
      less: {
        javascriptEnabled: true,
      },
    },
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: [
      { find: /^~/, replacement: "" },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    reactRefresh(),
    vitePluginImp({
      libList: [
        {
          libName: "antd",
          style: (name) => `antd/es/${name}/style`,
        },
      ],
    }),
  ],
});
```

> Also work with `@preact/preset-vite`.

---

**Ref:**

- https://github.com/theprimone/vite-react
- https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/7850
- https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/2185#issuecomment-784637827

Comment: When using `(name) => `antd/es/${name}/style`` my pre-bundling time has increased in time because it was importing all of the `antd/es` styles by separately. Could fix it by using `name => `antd/es/${name}/style/index.less``.

Answer (score 2):

Try to import antd styles like this:

```js
vitePluginImp({
  libList: [
    {
      libName: 'antd',
      style: (name) => `antd/es/${name}/style`,
    },
  ],
}),
```

More usage of Vite + React + Ant Design or other UI Library, this repo [theprimone/vite-react](https://github.com/theprimone/vite-react) might give you more or less inspiration.